# IBM Watson Assistant: How to replace "Built with IBM Watson" with something own?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I want to replace the built with IBM Watson with my own text, I able to remove it but not replace it.
I have already tried this according to the documentation but it changes the text in the header. There is no such information in the webchat framework on how to replace it.

```
   instance.writeableElements.headerBottomElement.innerHTML = 'Powered By <a target="_blank" href="https://www.rechtsanwalt.com" rel="noopener"><strong>Rechtsawalt</strong></a>';
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question with details of what you already tried and what in the documentation you read.